# error MSB3073: How do I fix this?

Tags: c++, mfc

```
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(113,5): error MSB3073: The command "copy "C:\Users\jlee\Desktop\10_IPG2.7_4\InitialPowerGadget\Release\EnergyLib.dll" "C:\Users\jlee\Desktop\10_IPG2.7_4\InitialPowerGadget\Bins32\EnergyLib32.dll"
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(113,5): error MSB3073: copy "C:\Users\jlee\Desktop\10_IPG2.7_4\InitialPowerGadget\EnergyDriver\objfre_win7_x86\i386\EnergyDriver.sys" "C:\Users\jlee\Desktop\10_IPG2.7_4\InitialPowerGadget\Bins32"
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(113,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1.
```

I was researching online, I think it has to do something with relative pathing; but I'm not sure. Can someone help explain what is wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fix MSB3073 error in my post-build event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075279/how-do-i-fix-msb3073-error-in-my-post-build-event)

Comment: If copy fails then either paths must be invalid, file already exists and you are not forcing overwrite, no permissions to write, etc. It's going to be hard to tell from here without guessing. You can try putting that command into cmd.exe and see what happens.

Comment: @afuzzyllama That link was one of the first I found when trying to solve my own problem, but the solution from that link seems to be to specific to the problem itself, that it was hard for me to understand the overall problem and solution for this type of problem. That's why I decided to just ask again.

Comment: copy the command from the VS output and run it on the command line, then check the errors

Comment: @Matt cmd couldn't find the files specified... So does this mean I have to copy the files and place it into the specified path?

Comment: @CodeDoctorJL that means something wrong with the path you specified for the copy command

Comment: @Matt Oh, I tried again it said "Access is denied, 0 file(s) copied"

Answer (score 14):

My problem was that the target directory contained spaces i.e.

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\projects\blah
```

So for me the solution was to wrap `$(TargetDir)` in double quotes i.e.

```
copy ..\resources\\* "$(TargetDir)" /Y
```

Answer (score 13):

In my case the problem was that VC++ was trying to copy a .dll file into a system folder. Running it as administrator fixed the problem.

Comment: God bless you! Worked for me!!! I had `Severity Code Description Project File Line Category Source Suppression State Tool
Error MSB3073 The command "copy "bin\Release\*" "C:\Program Files\Rockstar Games\Grand Theft Auto V\*"
:VCEnd" exited with code 1. DeepGTAV C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets 133  Build  
`

Comment: Fixed it for me! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the following situation:
I was trying to overwrite write-protected files with an post-build event copy. I need some time to find it out because I copied various files, some were copied with success some not. But for all events an error was displayed. In the example below copy event 4, 5 and 6 failed which was indicated before the error with "Zugriff verweigert" (engl.: access denied):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Get it. I have set up a post build event to run the unit tests automatically after each build. Delete this configure, can solve this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same error code. In my case, I just forget to close the previously built executable program.

Answer (score -2):

Just add your user to permission for cmd.exe file in system32.
that will solve this problem.