# windows defender modified Microsoft.CppCommon.targets

Tags: compiler-errors, msbuild, visual-studio-2019, windows-defender

[image]

so it happened because Windows defender was doing some process and it edited somehow because windows defender detected my visual studio output file as dangerous trojan or something.

I really don't know what to do, please help

Comment: Actually, I think it may have objected to `DemoPlayer.dll`.  Have a look at the Defender Protection History to check.  Also, please post error messages as text, not images or links to images.

Comment: **1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: The command "copy C:\Users\TERMINATOR\Desktop\NorAdrenaline\Release\NorAdrenaline.dll ..\bin
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(149,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1.
Done building project "NorAdrenaline.vcxproj" --FAILED.
Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed**
I already restored all detections in Defender and no, it happens on any project, i use VS 2019

Comment: EDIT:
I found issue. Its in project solution but i dont know where to fix it.
https://i.imgur.com/TEz4q4Z.png
it cant find path or something

Comment: Looks like your post-build step.  You can edit that in the configuration pages.  Please stop posting [links to] images.

Comment: l think you should check the post build event or pre-build event (Right-click on your project-->Properties-->Build Event) to see whether the command executes correctly. And the `exited with code 1` means system cannot find the specific files. And l found that the command is doing an copy task, so please check whether  the original file and destination folder paths are correct or accessible. In addition, you could share the commands with us  which could be helpful to sovle  your issue.

Answer (score 0):

> windows defender modified Microsoft.CppCommon.targets

The issue is caused by the wrong command line which is written in the post-build event or pre-build event of Configuration pages just as **Paul** said. You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914339/error-msb3073-how-do-i-fix-this).

Please check it by Right-click on your Project-->`Properties-->Configuration Properties-->Build Event-->Pre-Build Event/Post-Build Event/Pre-Link Event-->Command Line`.

The command in your project is like this:

```
copy xxxxxxxxx\Noradrenaline.dll ..\bin
```

If the `Noradrenaline.dll` is the output file of your project, you should write the command in the **post-build event**(This event executes after the build finishes and the corresponding output file can only be found after the build).

**Besides**, if `Noradrenaline.dll` is not the output file of the project, please make sure the path is accessible and the `bin` folder already exists.

**In addition**, from the perspective of your command, you want to copy a specific file to a folder.

The destination address of the [copy command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/copy) must include the name of the file, such as `.. \ bin \ Noradrenaline.dll`.

```
xcopy path1 path2
```

**path1** is the path of the source file(like xxx\xxx.dll), **path2** is the destination address and you also remember adding the name to the destination address( like xxx\xxx.dll).

**To sum up**, if both two paths can access without any problems, you would better write like this:

```
copy xxxxxxxxx\Noradrenaline.dll ..\bin\Noradrenaline.dll
```

Hope it could help you.