# Publishing App Failure in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: .net, visual-studio, publish

When I am trying to publish my web app I am getting this error :
23>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5719,5): error MSB3073:
I dont know what could be the reason because the project builds successfully and is running all fine on my pc.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the issue is that the target directory contains spaces. If that's the case, the solution was to wrap $(TargetDir) in double quotes instead.
Some other times it is due to a .dll file copy attempt into a system folder. Running it as administrator fixed the problem.
Other common solution is to open a command prompt as an administrator and run the command:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\gacutil.exe" /if "E:\path\path\buildoutput\whatever.dll"

[Error MSB3073](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/f9dc78a1-f126-428b-9fd0-75b53353d8e1/error-msb3073-by-compiling-solution-the-command-quotquotprogramfilesmicrosoft?forum=netfxsetup)

[error MSB3073: How do I fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914339/error-msb3073-how-do-i-fix-this)