# Visual Studio C++ Makefile Project Error Code 9009 - MSB3073

Tags: c++, visual-studio, makefile, visual-studio-2015

I've just installed Visual Studio Community 2015 and tried making a makefile project.

After I made the project, I made a file called main.cpp in the source file folder and put a correct hello world code in C++

I went to Debug -> Start Without Debugging and this error appeared
**Error MSB3073 The command "build" exited with code 9009.**

In this file **C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets**

This is the line which is giving the error [image]

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075279/how-do-i-fix-msb3073-error-in-my-post-build-event

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it did not work is because I didn't have make in my path.
Which mean when I opened command prompt and wrote "make" it would say that the command was not found, which is the opposite of what I needed for it to work.

I simply went to "Advanced System Settings" -> "Enviorment Variables" -> In "System Variables" I found "Path" and added the path of the folder where make.exe was (In my case it was in "\C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\")

Answer (score 0):

You could also go into your solution project properties, and find the Executable Directories path.

The difference is that adding it to the system path for all of Windows, but putting it in the project path works for only that visual studio project.