# how to properly use COPY instruction in postBuild action

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I would like to perform postBuild action in MS Visual Studio 2022 / C# project.

The action is to copy the executable into a different folder. However the folder is not yet created so the `copy` instruction fails. How to use the `copy` instruction in a way it creates the required directory or something other like `mkdir`? Is anywhere a list of available commands?

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
  <Exec Command="MKDIR $(SolutionDir)Outputs&#xD;&#xA;copy /Y $(TargetDir)$(TargetName).exe $(SolutionDir)Outputs\$(TargetName).exe" />
</Target>
```

Comment: A directory `Outputs` is created when I use your code, and it does contain an executable. => not reproducible ?

Comment: Not exactly. It does create the output in first build but fails to copy. Then on second build it is copying properly. Maybe the commands are executed in parallel and not sequentially?

Comment: I just removed the directory `Outputs`, and here it is re-created with a build, and does contain the exe file (    `fc Outputs\myProject.exe myProject\bin\Debug\net6.0\myProject.exe
Comparing files OUTPUTS\myProject.exe and myProject\BIN\DEBUG\NET6.0\myProject.EXE
FC: no differences encountered` )

Comment: And what I get is:
2>...Proj.csproj(17,5): error MSB3073: The command "MKDIR E:\...\Outputs
2>...Proj.csproj(17,5): error MSB3073: copy /Y E:\...\MyLib.dll E:\...\" exited with code 1.

Comment: When you have different projects in your solution: [How do I fix MSB3073 error in my post-build event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075279/how-do-i-fix-msb3073-error-in-my-post-build-event)

Comment: About the list of available command, it is somewhere down here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-concepts?view=vs-2022    (which is on my long list to read sometimes... )